# for loop in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, for

I want to create a for loop that runs from 1 to a number stored in a variable. But it produces this error:

> Syntax error: Bad for loop variable

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

count_lines () 
{
  local f=$1  
  l=`wc -l $f | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/'`
}
echo "$0 counts the lines of code" 
l=0
while [ "$*" != ""  ]
do
        count_lines $1
        echo "$1: $l"
        shift
done
for(( i= 0 ; i <= ${l} ; i++))
do
   title=$(grep -oPm1 "(?<=<title>)[^<]+" <<< "$0")
   echo "$title"
done
```

Comment: Small trick: `wc -l <filename` (note the left-angle) outputs just the count and you don't need to fiddle with `sed` or even something cheaper like `${var% *}`. That said, if you really want to look for XML construct(s?) in the file(s?) they are unlikely to be related to the number of lines; one of the main features of XML is that it is stream-oriented, not line-oriented.

Comment: `for (( i= 0 ; i <= ${l} ; i++))` space missing here. And in `(( ))` use `i <= l` -- `${}` is unnecessary and a missing l actually messes up with the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the script is executable, and run the script by just typing the command, including its path. For example, if the script is called `foo` and is in the current directory, run

```
./foo
```

Given the error message, you are doing something like `sh foo`. This runs the script under `sh`, not `bash`. `sh` on your machine is a different shell, probably dash, which doesn't support the for loop syntax you used. By running `./foo`, your script will be executed by the shell mentioned in the first line, which is bash.

Your script is weird in several places:

- [Always put double quotes around variable substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters): `"$1"`, `"$f"`, etc.
- That `while [ "$*" != ""  ] …` loop is a very roundabout way of iterating over the arguments of the script. The simple, idiomatic way is

  ```
  for x; do
    count_lines "$x"
  done
  ```

  or

  ```
  for x in "$@"; do
    count_lines "$x"
  done
  ```
- I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `title=$(grep -oPm1 "(?<=<title>)[^<]+" <<< "$0")`; `"$0"` is the path to the script, so you're searching the regexp `(?<=<title>)[^<]+` in the path to the script, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I'm trying to extract a value from an xml document that has been read into my script as a variable with title=$(grep -oPm1 "(?<=<title>)[^<]+" <<< "$0")

Comment: and I wish to extract the all values between titles with a loop

Comment: @engineer Fix the parts you understand, then post a new question with your updated script, some sample input, and the desired output.

Comment: I test my machine's shell with ps -p $$ and it is bash @Gilles

Comment: @engineer That shows you which shell you're running interactively. But given the error message you got, you are not running the script with bash. Once again, run `/path/to/script` instead of `sh /path/to/script` or whatever it is you're doing.

Comment: @ Gilles runing with  /path/to/script didn't show anything no strings,no error...etc

Comment: @engineer Having no error is progress. Now you need to fix your script to do what you actually want. Your `grep` command isn't searching in the input files, so it's not surprising that you aren't finding anything. Once again, please stop commenting here and ask a new question with your updated script, some sample input, and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I believe is with not testing if the file actually exists and getting a count `l` that is invalid for the `for` loop.

Take a look at this (very modified) similar script to give you some ideas:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

count_lines() {
if [[ -r $1 ]]; then     # if the file exist.
  l="$(wc -l "$1")"      # count the number of lines.
  l="${l%%[^0-9]*}"      # remove anything that is not a digit from the end.
else
  l=0
fi
}
echo "$0 counts the lines of code"

for file; do               # while there is an argument.
  count_lines "$file"    # execute the function above
  echo "$file: $l"       # print the number of lines.
done

echo "$(grep -oPm1 "(?<=<title>)[^<]+" "$0")"
```

I can not understand why you try to run `l` times a command (grep) to find `title` inside a file. One time is enough.

Also, the grep command is reading the script (not an external file).

As Gilles said: heavily correct your code, post a new question.